# How to center a div with max-width and absolute positioning to work in IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I want to center absolute position div that has max-width.

```
#confirmation-popup {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 12px;
  background-color: #4e4e4e;
}
```

This does not work in **IE**.

Comment: Which version of IE?

Comment: all .include ie10 and dege

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`max-width` doesn't work in IE. better use `width` or you can use translate technique.

here is the snippet:

```css
#confirmation-popup {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 12px;
  background-color: #4e4e4e;
}
```

```html
<div id="confirmation-popup">this is demo</div>
```